# How to solve Android "E/Capability﹕ Standby get error" and "E/Capability﹕ Active get error" on Orange Pi 2G IOT

Tags: android, adb

Recently I bought an Orange Pi 2G IOT board which runs Android 4.4.2 by default.

This device has not an lcd display nor an hdmi port. So i just do tests/development just using ADB for shell/system prorgamming (it is root device) or via Android Studio App development.

Every thing went ok, but after a while I no more could run app from android studio and the logcat shown following two errors for multiple apps.

"E/Capability﹕ Standby get error"
"E/Capability﹕ Active get error"

Please help me on how to solve it.

Comment: I did a factory reset on the device using adb: `adb shell su -c am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR` but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I also flashed the android os image I got from the official Orange Pi 2G IOT materials using the tools they provide in their site, following this guide: ( http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2687 ), but the same behavior is seen again. Seems that there is a hardware damage to the board, or a usb cable problem, or some configuration change in the Android studio logcat.

Comment: I also noticed that following errors occurs: `E/memtrack? Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)` and `E/android.os.Debug? failed to load memtrack module: -2`. Since any logcat message that I see starts with E\\* and also due to E\android.os.Debug error, I guessed that something has happened to reporting Log.d() messages. So I changed all of my app messages from `Log.d(...)` to `Log.e(...)` and now I see that my app is running and the E\\* messages from my app is visible in my logcat.  Strange Thing! So that may not be a hardware problem since other debug messages work well.